# Why I got an TypeError: Cannot read property in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have arrays:

- **sportmen** (like this: [{id: 1, surname: 'Williams', typeSport: 5}, ...])
- **sports** (like this: [{id: 4, name: 'football'}, ...])

I using map function to send every sportsman from Main component to ListRow component:

```
{this.props.sportsmen.map(item => {
    return (<ListRow key={item.id} directory={item}/>);
})}
```

In ListRow component I print all data about every sportsman, but id value typeSport I changing to sport name. **My realization is working**, but I have an error in console.

```
showSport() {
    const tmpSport = this.props.sports.find(item => item.id === this.props.directory.typeSport);
    return tmpSport.name;  // error is here!
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.props.directory.surname}</div>
            <div>{this.showSport()}</div>        
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'name' of undefined

Why I get this error and how can I remove errors?

Comment: Can you debug `tmpSport` by doing a `console.log(tmpSport)` what is the result of this?

Comment: @Variable I have 6 calls: 4 undefined and 2 with data (which will show in row, like this: {id: 15, surname: 'Wilson', typeSport: 4})

Comment: @varit05 How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sports array doesn't contain a sport whose id matches this.props.directory.typeSport. one solution would be to modify what is returned to handle cases where the sport doesn't exist.

```
return tmpSport ? tmpSort.name : 'not found'
```

or something like that